# How to skip the needed amount of bytes in output file using dd utility?

Tags: linux, dd

I want to rewrite a specific area in an output file with an input file using dd utility, I need to skip the first 732618 bytes in the output file and write 708800 bytes starting from there, I found only how to skip bytes in the input file, but cant finds info how to skip it in the output file,  is it possible to do with dd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page says:

> `seek=N` skip `N` `obs`-sized blocks at start of output

You probably want `conv=notrunc` too, to not truncate the output.

```
$ echo abcdefghijkl > foo.txt
$ echo -n XYZ | dd bs=1 seek=3 of=foo.txt conv=notrunc
3+0 records in [...]
$ cat foo.txt
abcXYZghijkl
```

Note that if you use `bs=1` as above, it will issue one `write()` system call per byte read and written, so it will be slow. I wouldn't try to set `obs` to the full  732618 though, since it (AFAIK) `dd` doesn't retry partial writes.

With GNU dd, you could add `oflag=seek_bytes` and then give the seek offset as just bytes, allowing a saner block size.

---

Alternatively, use Perl to do the seeking:

```
$ echo abcdefghijkl > foo.txt
$ echo -n XYZ | ( perl -e 'sysseek STDOUT, 3, 0;'; cat ) 1<> foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt 
abcXYZghijkl
```